# What should I watch to debug this Core-Data / NSFetchedResultsController bug?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've got a bug in my Core Data implementation that I cannot seem to get a hold of, and I need some tips on where I should be looking to figure out how to fix it.

To make a long story short, I have a `UITableView` being populated by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. I want my users to be able to change the sorting options for the data, so I give them a picker that will change the underlying `fetchedResultsController` to different preset configurations. I can change back and forth between the different `fetchedResultsControllers` with no issue whatsoever. I can add and remove data, never experiencing any crashes, no problem. However, on 2 (out of 6, and always the same 2) of the `fetchedResultController` configurations, items added to the database are not added to the tableview. And items that are in the tableview disappear once edited.

Here are the steps I go through to reproduce the bug:

1. Set the sorting to a configuration that works
2. Add a new item to the database (at this point `controllerWillChangeContent` fires)
3. Change to a configuration that doesn't work
4. Add a new item to the database (`controllerWillChangeContent` does not fire)
5. Switch back to the working configuration
6. The item added is now visible in the `tableView`
7. Switch back to the non-working configuration
8. The item is now visible in the `tableView`
9. Edit the item (`controllerWillChangeContent` is fired, but `controller:DidChangeObject:` is fired with the type as `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` instead of `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`)
10. Change back to the working configuration, and the item is changed and visible again.

I'm at my wits end with this thing. I'm completely out of ideas. There is literally no difference between the way these 2 `fetchedResultsControllers` are created and the 4 others. *Any* help that can be offered will be *greatly* appreciated.

### --EDIT--

Still having some issues with this. To reiterate some of the answers to TechZen's questions:

- None of my attributes are set as transient values
- I'm using a flat model at the moment. It's a single entity with direct attributes. There are no relationships.
- The problem persists with the caches set to `nil`
- I am setting the old `frc`'s delegate to `nil` before every change, and setting the new `frc`'s delegate to `self` at the end of the switch. This is consistant across all 6 `frc`s
- I am releasing the old `frc` and creating a new one each time the user switches to a different sort option.

For those interested, the code I'm using to switch the `frc` is in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/724326)

### -- EDIT 2 --

Starting a bounty for anyone that can point me in the right direction on this.

### -- Edit 3 --

As requested, here is the code for my Delegate Methods:

```
-(void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
            
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

    }
}

-(void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            if (!self.searchIsActive) {
                [self configureCell:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            } else {
                [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
            }
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    } 
}


-(void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

And the info got my Data Model:

```
// Person.h
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface Person :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * company;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * comments;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * job;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * logDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * location;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * rating;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imagePath;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * thumbPath;

@end

// Person.m
#import "Person.h"

@implementation Person 

@dynamic name;
@dynamic company;
@dynamic comments;
@dynamic job;
@dynamic logDate;
@dynamic location;
@dynamic rating;
@dynamic imagePath;
@dynamic thumbPath;

@end
```

Info about the data model:

```
Entity: Person
    Property: comments
        kind: attribute
        type: string
        optional: YES
    Property: name
        kind: attribute
        type: string
        optional: NO
    Property: rating
        kind: attribute
        kind: Int 16
        optional: YES
        min value: 0
        max value: 5
    Property: job
        kind: attribute
        kind: string
        optional: YES
    Property: company
        kind: attribute
        kind: string
        optional: YES
    Property: location
        kind: attribute
        kind: string
        optional: YES
    Property: imagePath
        kind: attribute
        kind: string
        optional: YES
    Property: thumbPath
        kind: attribute
        kind: string
        optional: YES
    Property: logDate
        kind: attribute
        kind: date
        optional: YES
```

Nothing too special about any of this.

Comment: Will you please post the code related to all of your NSFetchedResultsController delegate methods, and the data model you are using?

Comment: @unforgiven Added a bunch of code to the question. Let me know if there's something else you want to see.

Comment: Both the "job" and "location" attributes are optional. Does the new item you add in one of the broken configuration actually contain values for these attributes? It may be that an item is not added to the table because, owing to its attributes values and your NSFetchedResultsController setup, it is simply not fetched at all. For the same reasons, it may be that, once edited, an item disappear from the table (because it no longer belong to the table after editing).

Comment: You're my hero. That fixed it. Submit an answer so that I can award you the bounty. Is there any way to set a Null Value as the default for those attributes?

Comment: Nevermind. Just added an empty string to those attributes when saving the object, and all is now well. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reposting this comment as answer, as requested.

Both the "job" and "location" attributes are optional. Does the new item you add in one of the broken configuration actually contain values for these attributes? It may be that an item is not added to the table because, owing to its attributes values and your NSFetchedResultsController setup, it is simply not fetched at all. For the same reasons, it may be that, once edited, an item disappear from the table (because it no longer belong to the table after editing).

**EDIT**:

To set an initial value different from nil, in your Core Data Person.m file add the following method

```
- (void) awakeFromInsert{
    self.job = @"";
    self.location = @"";
}
```

etc. This way, the initial values will be automatically inserted by Core Data each time you create a new person object.

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, setting the attribute to `[NSNull null]` was throwing a warning (Incompatible Objective-C types) and causeing a crash, but setting them to `@""` works great.

Comment: Ok, I am updating the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the FRC caches. Try setting them all to nil and see if it resolves.

It could be a problem with a transient property. I've noticed that fetches that use transient properties behave strangely at times.

More likely, however, it looks like a problem with assignment of the FRC delegate. The new or edited object will only appear in the UI if the UI controller receives the FRC delegate messages. It seems like they are not receiving the delegate messages reliably.

If the FRCs not in use are still alive and still have their delegate set, then you might be getting collisions between their messages to the delegate. Any change to the persistent store from any source could trigger any FRC to fire off delegate messages. The messages hitting the delegate may not be from the FRC you intend to be active.

Make sure that the FRC not in use have a nil delegate set.

Comment: Problem persists with the caches set to `nil`. None of my properties are set to transient. In the method where I change the FRC, the very first thing I do is set the current FRC delegate to `nil`. I set the new FRC's delegate to `self` at the end of the method. None of the individual FRCs change this behavior.

Comment: I would suggest starting with just one of the FRC that fails and confirm that it works in isolation with the other FRC completely inactive (never initialized.) Then add the second failing FRC and see if that works. Keep adding them back in until they fail. That will let you isolate the problem.

Comment: I'm actually releasing the old FRC and creating a new one each time the sort option is changed. The full code for the method is in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/724326). However, even if I never change my sort method, and start the app clean with this sort option in place, these problems persist.

Comment: Looking at your code, I don't see any obvious problems with the FRC or its components. I would look at the data model. If you don't have inverse relationships set for all relationships, then changes might not be noticed by an FRC which watches only one side of the relationship. If the problem is with two specific FRC then the problem has to be either in the configuration of the fetch or the data model.

Comment: You might possibly have a sorting collision between `firstAttribute` sort and the `sectionNameKeyPath` By default, the section name performs its own hard corded sort based on the first letter of the value of the `sectionNameKeyPath`. Since you also do a sort on the same attribute, in theory, you might get some kind of collision between the two sorts in certain circumstances. That's just a wild guess

Comment: Scratch that last if you are using iOS 4.2. The sectionNameKeyPath now uses the first provided sort.

Comment: It's a flat model. 1 entity with direct attributes. So unless I'm misunderstanding, there really shouldn't be any difference, right? And the problem persists into 4.2, so I can check that second thing off the list too, right? I keep coming back to it being a delegate issue, but I can't figure out why.